# css not working, one class not loading

Tags: css

On a fiddle the css is working correct. On my website the 'roman' doesn't load.
If i check the css it's present, i also deleted my cache but that doesn't help either.

I hope this info will cover all to solve the problem.

Here some html:

```
<li data-item="Content">Content
<ul class="roman">
<li data-target="inleiding.html"><span></span><span>Inleiding</span></li>
<li data-target="c1.html"><span>I</span><span>Het tijdperk der goden</span></li>
<li data-target="c2.html"><span>II</span><span>Helden en Krijgslieden</span></li>
<li data-target="c3.html"><span>III</span><span>De Bamboesnijder en het maanmeisje</span></li>
<li data-target="c4.html"><span>IV</span><span>Legenden omtrent Buddha</span></li>
<li data-target="c5.html"><span>V</span><span>Legenden omtrent vossen</span></li>
<li data-target="c6.html"><span>VI</span><span>Jizō, de god van Kinderen</span></li>
<li data-target="c7.html"><span>VII</span><span>De Legende in de Japansche Kunst</span></li></ul>
</li>
```

This is my css

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
    height: auto;
}

/* normal */
.column_n {
    width: 480px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    border-left: 1px dashed pink; 
}

/* small */
.column_s {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    border-left: 1px dashed pink; 
}

/* menu (small) */
#menu {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    background-color: #004249;
}


#m_console {
    position: fixed;
    background: yellow;
    left: 5px;
    top: 25px;
}

#book {
    width: 1402px;
}

.b_footnote {
    background: yellow;
    /* position: absolute; */
    width: 450px; 
    /* width: auto; */

    /* left: 540px; */
    /* z-index: 99; */
}

.b_image {
    width: 410px;
}​

.roman {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: normal;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

.roman li {
    display: table-row;
}

.roman span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1px 4px;
}
```

Here a fiddle where it does work.
http://jsfiddle.net/nCs99/6/

Comment: Do you have a live site? I just copied everything from thre jsFiddle to a standalone HTML file, and the result looks the same as the result in the jsFiddle itself.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're trying to make a list look like a table that looks like a list. Why not use... a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) can help you to extensively debug your CSS files. Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> after installing it and head to HTML or CSS tab. According to your code, nothing is wrong but we don't know what is interfering with the classes or tags in the end.

Comment: i looked at it but i have no clue what goes wrong.
Could u take a look?
http://doekewartena.nl/artez/webdesign/mobile_reader/gyroReader/gyroReader.php

Comment: According to Firebug there is a whitespace before ".roman" (at line 72) it blocks the recognizition of CSS class. Just try to remove the and enter a new line or rewrite ".roman" completely. It doesn't actually show up in the code.